# Why %in% in R is not matching properly?

Tags: r

I am new to R. I have created two vectors 'a' and 'b' in R. Both of them contains the same elements, but in different order. Following are the details of 2 vectors.

```
> str(a)
Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame':   369 obs. of  1 variable:
$ SKD_DOCUMENT_NO: chr  "A0000514011" "A0000514012" "A0000514013" "A0000514014" ...
> str(b)
Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame':   369 obs. of  1 variable:
$ SKD_DOCUMENT_NO: chr  "A0000648001" "A0000648050" "A0000648049" 
"A0000648048" ...
```

but when I try to check whether an element is in the vectors or not, i get confusing answers from R.

```
>'A0000648050' %in% a   #[1] FALSE 
>"A0000648050" %in% a   #[1] FALSE
```

But when I try to use other methods to check whether the element is in 'a'. Then following results come:

```
> any(a == "A0000648050")       #[1] TRUE
> which(a == "A0000648050")     #[1] 115
> grep("A0000648050", a)        #[1] 1
```

Q1. What I don't understand is why %in% is failing.

Q2. What is the easiest way to find if all elements of 'a' vector are present in all elements of 'b' vector? (all elements of 'a' are indeed present in 'b'. But would like to be confirmed from R). Why does following 2 lines give different results?

```
> a %in% b            #[1] FALSE
> setequal(a,b)       # TRUE
```

Comment: Q1: `a` is a `tibble` / `data.frame`, not a vector. Try `'A0000648050' %in% a$SKD_DOCUMENT_NO`. Q2: `?all`

Comment: Somy introductory texts and answers on SO use the tidyverse - difficult for beginners to see what is basic R and what is not.

Answer (score 1):

**%in%**

From `?'%in%'` :

> %in% is currently defined as  "%in%" <- function(x, table) match(x,
>   table, nomatch = 0) > 0
>
> Factors, raw vectors and lists are converted to character vectors, and
>   then x and table are coerced to a common type (the later of the two
>   types in R's ordering, logical < integer < numeric < complex <
>   character) before matching. If incomparables has positive length it is
>   coerced to the common type.

in your case `a` is a `tibble`, which is a `data.frame`, which is a `list`, so it's converted to character before the comparison takes place.

```
a <- tibble(SKD_DOCUMENT_NO =c("A0000514011","A0000514012","A0000514013","A0000514014"))
as.character(a)
# [1] "c(\"A0000514011\", \"A0000514012\", \"A0000514013\", \"A0000514014\")"
```

This, though it's not intuitive, will return `TRUE`:

```
"c(\"A0000514011\", \"A0000514012\", \"A0000514013\", \"A0000514014\")" %in% a
```

**any**

from `?any`, on the `...` argument:

> Other objects of zero length are ignored, and the rest are coerced to
>   logical ignoring any class.

```
a == "A0000514012"
#      SKD_DOCUMENT_NO
# [1,]           FALSE
# [2,]            TRUE
# [3,]           FALSE
# [4,]           FALSE
```

The following happens when we coerce it to logical:

```
as.logical(a == "A0000514012")
# [1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

so the output you get with `any(a == "A0000514012")` makes sense.

The same exercise can be done with `which` or `grep`

**solution**

The solution is to use either:

```
"A0000514012" %in% a$SKD_DOCUMENT_NO # to look into a precise column
```

or

```
"A0000514012" %in% unlist(a) # to look into all columns, equivalent to your solution with `any`
```

or

```
sapply(a,`%in%`,x = "A0000514012") # to look into individual columns separately
```